# Get request token from ADFS SAML .NET server from Java

Tags: java, .net, saml, adfs, saaj

I am trying to connect to a web service (**WSDL** file) in **.NET** from **Java**, but I am unable to authenticate. The authentication is based on **ADFS SAML**.

I have used all the libraries: Axis, Axis2, JAX-WS, Metro but none of them are working for me.

So then I just made a **SOAPEnvelope** in **SAAJ** and am just sending it without any other 3rd party library. Now I know exactly what is being sent.

What I don't know, is how to populate the header message correctly? The server is using **TransportWithMessageCredential** security mode with **clientCredentialType="UserName"**.

Since its **SAML**, I need to send a message with credentials that will send be back a token that I can use in my subsequent messages.

How do I make that request message that returns me the **SAML** token?

Answer (score 0):

In order to talk SAML to ADFS, you need a [client-side SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

So you can authenticate via the SAML stack to ADFS and get a SAML token back.

There is a SOAP binding for SAML but it is not supported by ADFS.

Comment: I didn't get your meaning in the last sentence, SOAP binding not supported by ADFS?

Comment: In other words, you can't authenticate to ADFS via SOAP.

Comment: Thanks! So I need to use lets say OpenSAML to get the token, and then make a request message (actual data operation) with that token and send that to the web service, correct?

Comment: Correct - but the web service will have to be able to accept a SAML token.

Comment: Their system is called ADFS SAML, I'd think it will accept that. I just can't figure out how to set all the other attributes that will go in the message, like how do I generate the MessageID etc.